# Use node module in browser

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js

I'm using the very simple [Refify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/refify) npm module to handle circular structure JSON. It stringifies a circular structure JSON object in Node.js to then send to the client. My Angular frontend receives the stringified JSON and needs to call the `parse` method of refify to convert it back to a usable object.

How do I include the refify node module in my Angular frontend so I can reference refify?

Backend usage looks like so:

```
var refify = require("refify");
app.get("/api/entries, function(req, res){ 
  var circularJSON = //a circular JSON object
  res.send(refify.stringify(circularJSON));
});
```

The frontend reference would look like this:

```
$http.get("/api/entries").success(function(data){
  $scope.entries = refify.parse(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the forked version of Refify you can use in node.js as well as browsers.

**[Forked Refify](https://github.com/jigardafda/refify)**

You can simply download the [`index.js`](https://github.com/jigardafda/refify/blob/master/index.js) and include it in your AngularJS application. and use it.

see the below code, I have added the whole forked `index.js` file in snippet and example at the end.

```js
(function(obj) {
  if (typeof exports === 'undefined') {
    obj.refify = refify;
  } else {
    module.exports = refify;
  }


  function refify(obj) {
    var objs = [];
    var paths = []

    var keyStack = [];
    var objStack = [];

    return walk(obj);

    function walk(it) {
      if (typeof it !== 'object') {
        return it;
      }
      objs.push(it);
      paths.push(keyStack.slice())
      objStack.push(it)
      var copy = initCopy(it);
      for (var k in it) {
        keyStack.push(k);
        var v = it[k];
        var i = objs.indexOf(v);
        if (i == -1) {
          copy[k] = walk(v)
        } else {
          var $ref = '#/' + paths[i].join('/');
          copy[k] = {
            $ref: $ref
          };
        }
        keyStack.pop();
      }
      objStack.pop();
      return copy;
    }
  }

  refify.parse = function(it) {
    if (typeof it !== 'object') it = JSON.parse(it);

    var keyStack = [];
    var copy = initCopy(it);

    walk(it);

    return copy;

    function walk(obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
        set(copy, keyStack.slice(), obj);
        return;
      }
      for (var k in obj) {
        keyStack.push(k);
        var current = obj[k];
        var objPath = parseRef(current);
        while (objPath) {
          current = get(copy, objPath);
          objPath = parseRef(current);
        }
        if (current === obj[k]) {
          // We did *not* follow a reference
          set(copy, keyStack.slice(), initCopy(current));
          walk(current);
        } else {
          // We *did* follow a reference
          set(copy, keyStack.slice(), current);
        }
        keyStack.pop();
      }
    }
  }

  refify.stringify = function(obj, replacer, spaces) {
    return JSON.stringify(refify(obj), replacer, spaces)
  }

  function parseRef(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'object') return false;
    if (!value.$ref) return false;
    var path = value.$ref == '#/' ? [] : value.$ref.split('/').slice(1);
    return path
  }

  function get(obj, path) {
    if (!path.length) return obj;
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') return;
    var next = obj[path.shift()];
    return get(next, path);
  }

  refify.set = set;

  function set(obj, path, value) {
    if (path.length === 0) throw new Error("Cannot replace root object");
    var key = path.shift();
    if (!path.length) {
      obj[key] = value;
      return;
    }
    switch (typeof obj[key]) {
      case 'undefined':
        obj[key] = isNaN(parseInt(key, 10)) ? {} : [];
        break;
      case 'object':
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error("Tried to set property " + key + " of non-object " + obj[key]);
    }
    set(obj[key], path, value);
  }

  function initCopy(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') return obj;
    return Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {}
  }

}(this));


// Example with forked version

var obj = {
  inside: {
    name: 'Stackoverflow',
    id: '98776'
  }
};

obj.inside.parent = obj;

var refifyObject= refify(obj);

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(refifyObject);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Just what I needed thanks! I did originally try just including the index.js from the node module but it just showed an error in my browser console 'module not defined'. This version works perfectly though.

Comment: in original version `index.js` was only doing `module.exports = refify;` which only works in the node.js. in forked version i simply added condition to check whether the environment is node.js or browser and then assign `Refify` accordingly. you can see the code diff https://github.com/jigardafda/refify/commit/1c7980ea835a0d1fddf457a814916668369d4803#diff-168726dbe96b3ce427e7fedce31bb0bc

Answer (score 2):

You can either use browserify as a build step, or you could use wzrd.in CDN, which is a CDN for npm modules.

### browserify as a build step

Use node-style `require()` to organize your browser code and load modules installed by npm.  Browserify will recursively analyze all the require() calls in your app in order to build a bundle you can serve up to the browser in a single `<script>` tag.  For more information, and examples, [click here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

### [wzrd.in](http://wzrd.in) CDN

```
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/refify@latest"></script>
<script>
    window.refify // You can use refify now!
</script>
```

You can go to https://wzrd.in/standalone/refify@latest, copy the code, and paste it into your own file if you want. See [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a3xg4y4p/).

Comment: That CDN thing is pretty nifty! Worked a charm but a hosted version works better for me.

Comment: Note that you can go to https://wzrd.in, select almost any npm module, and get the browser-ready code. Copy and paste the code into your own file if you want. Obviously not every module works, but many that were not designed with the browser in mind, work great in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

if you want use  module in browser, you can use Commonjs and AMD

**for example :**

[requirejs.org](http://requirejs.org)

[browserify](http://browserify.org/)

[commonjs.org](http://commonjs.org)

[systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)

you can convert [refify](https://github.com/grncdr/refify/blob/master/index.js) to module ( browserify ,requirejs,commonjs,...) and use.

**Useful Links :**

[create module in RequireJS](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-library-with-requirejs/)

[writing modular js/](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)

Comment: Could you provide a quick example of converting refify to a js file with browserify that I can include in my HTML as a script tag?

Comment: if you want use browserify. i use https://wzrd.in/ . you can include https://wzrd.in/standalone/refify@latest in your project and use window.refify, next answer Joseph Dykstra referred to